# Transfer money in application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

My application is using transfer of fund between users. Here is flow of my application.

**User will register to my app. After that he recharge his account to send money to another user. When user will recharge his account App will provide him token(virtual money) to maintain his balance in application and to send another user. And then user who received token from another user will claim his money from application whenever he want. In between this my application is charging some minor amount to user when he send money to another user. So when any user will recharge account he will pay real time money and will get token and when another user who received that token will claim for money he will get paid from app. in real time**

In this scenario Can anyone suggest me how to maintain transaction of real money means which payment gateway I should use for both scenario 
1.when user recharge his account 
2. when user claim for his money

Right now I am using paypal as my PG. I want to use In-App purchase. For first scenario it is ok to use In-App purchase but for second sceanrio to transfer money from application account to user personal account I dont know how to use In-App purchase.Can anyone tell me how to achieve 2nd scenario through In-App purchase

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, **you cannot do so**.

According to Apple's [In-App Purchase Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf),

> There are a handful of important guidelines to keep in mind as you
> design your application:
>
> **• You must deliver your digital good or**
> **service within your app. Do not use In-App  Purchase to sell**
> **real-world goods and services.**
>
> • You must make your In-App Purchase
> items available to all of the devices  registered to a user.
>
> • You
> may sell credits or virtual currency provided they are used within the
> app and  do not have a time limit imposed upon them.
>
> • Items you offer for purchase may not contain, or relate to,
> pornography, hate speech, defamation, or gambling (simulated gambling
> is acceptable).
>
> • In-App Purchase items cannot be shared across
> applications.

Also, there is no mechanism for remitting money to another user's account through In-App Purchase.

Comment: yes if I use In-App instead of paypal then almost all criteria are matching you can see. Application is providing virtual money to user. It doesn't applying any type of time limit on it.. Receiver of that virtual money can receive their money back at any time there is nothing like that which expire money of user. Just one thing is that how to transfer money back to user's account. Does In-App purchase provide any API to transfer money to any user's bank account or any another account.?? Or if no then Can I use any other API for that part only????

Comment: You do not seem to understand. If you submit such an app to the App Store, it will be REJECTED, as it violates point number 1.

Comment: Yes I really dont understand. Can you explain me how it is violating 1st point???

Comment: You will be using the In-App Purchase API to send real-world money from point A to point B. That is the violation.

Comment: Okk...so that means I am transferring money from one person to another that's why it is real world good. So for that if I use 3rd party payment gateway like paypal or any other then is it ok???

Comment: I guess it would be OK. However, keep in mind that most such apps have  their own money transfer mechanism set up at their own end.

Comment: I am sorry. Can't help you there. Edit or post a new question asking for API suggestions

Comment: Ok but  you mentioned that "most such apps have their own money transfer mechanism set up at their own end." Can you please explain me this?

Comment: OK. Check this App For instance: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xoom-money-transfer/id529615515?mt=8

Comment: These people have set up their own mechanism for transferring money. They have their own servers, encryption, everything.